# Doing a complete nextCmd scan with PySNMP

Tags: python, networking, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to scan a device in my network with PySNMP and want to do a extensive walk through the MIB tree and see what I can find.
For this I wrote a script, which works quite well, but it does not finish the task.

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from os.path import exists
import sys


    # Create command generator
    cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

    # Function definition
    def snmp_get_next(OID, target_IP, target_port, target):

        if exists(target):
            sys.exit("The file '%s' already exists!" % target)
        else: 
            target_file = open(target, 'w+')

        # Getting values
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
            cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
            cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((target_IP, target_port)),
            OID,
            cmdgen.MibVariable('IF-MIB', '').loadMibs(),
            lexicographicMode=True, maxRows=100,
            ignoreNonIncreasingOid=True
        )

        # Printing errors and OID_name to file
        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
        else:
            if errorStatus:
                print('%s at %s' % (
                    errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
                    )
                )
            else:
                for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
                    for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                        target_file.write('- %s:\t OID: %s and value = %s\n' 
                                      % (OID, name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint())
                                      )
        target_file.close()
        print('Writing successful!')


        sys.exit(0)

    # Execution of function
    snmp_get_next(
                  tuple(map(int,raw_input('OID Tuple:\t').split(','))), 
                  raw_input('Target IP:\t'), 
                  raw_input('Target Port:\t'), 
                  raw_input('Target File:\t')
                 )
```

So, when i execute the script with starting tuple 1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,3 I get a file with about 100 entrys, the last entry has tuple 1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,21. Now when I use this last tuple as starting tuple it still finds more. 
Either I misunderstood something, or it does not what it's supposed to.

UPDATE:

I changed my code a bit and now it works almost like it's supposed to. The only problem is, that I can't leave out the "maxRows" parameter or else I get a timeout error message.

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from os.path import exists
import sys

# Turn on debugging
#debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc', 'secmod'))

# Enter parameters
target_IP           = raw_input('Target IP (192.168.13.100): ') or '192.168.13.100'
target_port         = raw_input('Target port (161): ') or 161
target_file_name    = raw_input('Target filename (.txt is added): ') + '.txt' 

# Check for already existing file
if exists(target_file_name):
    sys.exit("The file '%s' already exists!" % target_file_name)
else: 
    target_file = open(target_file_name, 'w+')

# Initialize counter to zero
counter = 0

# Create command generator
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

# Get data

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((target_IP, target_port)),
    '1.3', # <---- Does not seem perfect to me, but it works
    lexicographicMode=True, 
    maxRows=5000, #  <---- Can't be left out, but I want to
    ignoreNonIncreasingOid=True,
    lookupNames=True, 
    lookupValues=True
)

# Print errors and values to file
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    # Print error messages

    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        # Print values
        for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
            for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                counter += 1
                target_file.write("(%s)\t start_OID: %s\tvalue =\t%s\n" % (counter, name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))

        # Finish the operation                
        target_file.close()
        print('Writing to %s successful. %d lines have been written' % (target_file_name, counter))
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation of the example you are following](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v3-pull-whole-mib-with-options.html), the variable `maxRows` sticks out as relevant. 
The example sets it to 100, which you say is roughly the number of returned rows. (I would expect it to be exactly that number.)

So, try increasing `maxRows`!

Normally, an SNMP Walk would not limit itself to a certain number of rows. Instead, the proper termination criteria would be "have I received a response OID which is not a child of the OID I started at". It's not clear to me if this utility will terminate at that point. Worst case, it'll walk the whole MIB tree if you let it.

Comment: To walk the whole SNMP agent, you should remove maxRows parameter completely. Otherwise it may stop fetching data prematurely.

Comment: Oh, well, that's quite simple. I dont' know how I didn't see that. thank you. Now it works. The only thing I dont' understand is that I get a file with 200 rows, even though I entered 100 rows. It always gives me double the amount of rows I wanted - and the value of half of the rows is just the last digit of the OID.